# Create a checkpoint on a managed package class in a subscriber org at a specific line

Tags: isv, checkpoint

I'm investigating an exception that is occurring within a subscriber org of our managed package. I have the stack trace that identifies where the exception is being thrown and the steps to reproduce the problem.

As part of debugging the underlying issue I'd like to capture the state of some variables when the exception occurs. One way to do this would be to update the error handling and/or debugging code in the package at the point where the exception is thrown. However, that would require a new package version.

Instead I thought I'd use a checkpoint to grab the values directly out of the  heap.

After logging in via the LMA subscriber support I used the Developer Console to find the class that needed the checkpoint.

[image]

[image]

As the source of the managed class is hidden I can't set the checkpoint to be on the line indicated by the stack trace.

**How can I set the checkpoint ([ApexExecutionOverlayAction](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_tooling.meta/api_tooling/tooling_api_objects_apexexecutionoverlayaction.htm) in the Tooling API) to have the required line number?**

Answer (score 4):

One easy way I found to do this is to initially create the checkpoint/ApexExecutionOverlayAction on the first line in the developer console.

Then edit it via the Tooling API to be on the required line:

[image]

```
Select Id, Line, ScopeId, IsDumpingHeap, ExpirationDate, ExecutableEntityId 
from ApexExecutionOverlayAction 
where ExecutableEntityId = '01pC00000019LNmIAM' 
order by ExpirationDate desc
```

Check the `ExecutableEntityId` to the applicable Apex class Id as required.

Then just directly change the Line in the query result and save the row.

[image]

If you reload the dev console the Checkpoint Locations will update to the new line number.